# Laravel eloquant の with にて結合先テーブルのカラムを where 条件にしたい

Tags: laravel

・テーブル構成
itemは記事テーブルで、channelはサイトテーブルとなっております。
channel対itemは一対多となっております。
item:記事テーブル
channel:サイトテーブル

やりたいこととしてはカテゴリごとの記事を取得したいと思っております。
現在left joinを用いる以下のコードで取得はできておりますが、
この状態ですと取得に時間がかかってしまいます。

```
$items = Item::leftJoin('channel', 'item.channel_id', '=', 'channel.id')
->select(                                                               
    'item.id',                                                          
    'item.title',                                                       
    'item.description',                                                 
    'item.link',                                                        
    'item.pub_date',                                                    
    'item.channel_id',                                                  
    'channel.title as channel_title',                                   
)                                                                       
->orderBy('pub_date', 'desc')                                           
->where('category_id', '=', $category->id)                              
->paginate(200);
```

そこで withを用いて取得しようとおもっております。

```
$items = Item::with('channel')
->select(                                                               
    'item.id',                                                          
    'item.title',                                                       
    'item.description',                                                 
    'item.link',                                                        
    'item.pub_date',                                                    
    'item.channel_id',                                                  
    'channel.title as channel_title',                                   
)                                                                       
->orderBy('pub_date', 'desc')                                           
->where('channel.category_id', '=', $category->id)                              
->paginate(200);
```

しかし、 withでは itemにcategory_idをもっていないため
`->where('channel.category_id', '=', $category->id)`
が使用できません。
スマートな方法があれば教えていただけませんか？

テーブル構成は以下です。

channelテーブル

```
CREATE TABLE `channel` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `link` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `rss_link` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `sort` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=122 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

itemテーブル

```
CREATE TABLE `item` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `link` varchar(512) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `pub_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `channel_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `channel_id` (`channel_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=183691 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Answer (score 1):

whereHas()を組み合わせてはいかがでしょうか。

```
// Categoryテーブルに対するEloquentオブジェクトを想定
$category = (object) ['id' => 1];

$with = function ($q) use ($category) {
    $q->select(['id', 'title'])->where('category_id', $category->id);
};

$whereHas = function ($q) use ($category) {
    $q->where('category_id', $category->id);
};

$columns = [
    'id',
    'title',
    'description',
    'link',
    'pub_date',
    'channel_id',
];

$items = \App\Item::with(['channel' => $with])
    ->whereHas('channel', $whereHas)
    ->select($columns)
    ->orderBy('pub_date', 'desc')
    ->paginate(200);
```

尚、検証に使用したEloquentクラスは以下の通りです。

\App\Channel

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Channel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'channel';

    public function items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Item::class);
    }
}
```

\App\Item

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Item extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'item';

    public function channel()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Channel::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: すみません、質問を一部間違えておりました...
channel対itemは一対多となっております。
その場合ご教授いただいた方法は使えないでしょうか？

Comment: 失礼しました。関連するテーブルのshow create table結果を記載いただくと、認識合わせやすいと思います。

Comment: show create tableの結果を記載いたしました。ご確認いただけますでしょうか？@mamor

Comment: channel.category_idが見当たりませんが、漏れていますか？とりあえず、回答内容に一部間違いがあったので、その部分は修正しておきました。categoryテーブルが有り、その主キーと紐づくchannel.category_idが存在する想定になります。

Comment: すみません、漏れていました！
質問の方修正いたしました。
回答の修正ありがとうございます
試してみたいと思います！